# Can't access MySQL database on DigitalOcean droplet

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I have destroyed and recreated droplets a few times now. Basically after creating the droplet via SSH and changing the root password to one of my own choosing I would like to set up MySQL database using 'mysql -u root -p' - it asks me for my password, which I of course enter and then I get a response 'ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'. Am I using the right password??

Please also note that I am using WordPress One-Click Install on DigitalOcean

Thanks! Nick.

Comment: No, it does not sound like you are using the right password. Note your mysql password will be different to your SSH password. When you create droplets that come with mysql they will have a login message from the remote saying something like "welcome, your mysql password is xxx" or "write cat /modt.blah to get your mysql login details".

Comment: You can check if the password is correct by logging into the console using the `mysql -uroot -p ` command.

Comment: Yes there is a welcome message and it tells me 'The passwords for MySQL and the Wordpress users have been saved to: /root/.digitalocean_password' --- have tried to check there too but it says: 'Permission denied' ---- your command seems like there may be syntax error as it says command not found and if it is the same as what I initially wrote - then I require the password, which I have no idea as to how to obtain??